# Pause / resume Qthread from Worker

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

In the Worker Class I have two functions who works and control the thread, start() and abort()

```
void Worker::requestWork()
{
    mutex.lock();
    _working = true;
    _abort = false;
    qDebug()<<"Le thread travail de"<<this->myId<<" "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
    mutex.unlock();
   emit workRequested();
}

void Worker::abort()
{
    mutex.lock();
    if(_working) {
       _abort = true;
       qDebug()<<"Le thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId()<<" s'arrete";
    }
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

As you can see the workrequest emit a signal saying to the thread to start to work. And because the Worker Class is in the thread, how can I pause or restore it? From the worker class? from the MainWindow?

and now the Whole code.Mainwindow Class.

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :    
    QMainWindow(parent),    
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)    
    {    
        ui->setupUi(this);
        QObject::connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(command(QString)));
        thread = new QThread();
        worker = new Worker();
        worker->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(worker, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString)), ui->label,  SLOT(setText(QString)));
        connect(worker, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread, SLOT(start()));
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(doWork()));
        connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
     }

//QLineEdit send signal to slot "command" permit to control the thread
void MainWindow::command(QString text){
qDebug()<<"le message a bien ete intercepte";
qDebug()<<ui->lineEdit->text();
if (text.contains("help"))
    qDebug()<<"heeeelp";
if (text.contains("pause")){
     worker->Paused();
     if(thread->isRunning()){}
         //cond.wait()
}

if (text.contains("restart")){
    worker->Restarted();
    if (!thread->isRunning()){}
        //cond.wakeAll();
}

if (text.contains("stopped")){
    worker->Paused();
    thread->wait();
}
if (text.contains("start")){
    worker->requestWork();

}

if (text.contains("destroyed")){
    worker->destroyed();
}

}
```

So my question is: how to pause and restart the thread from the command() slot when the User insert "Pause" ?

Comment: By the way, about this `connect(worker, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread, SLOT(start()));` thread by itself not in thread, if it created in main thread, than it belongs to main thread.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a suitable description. Also, provide a minimal but complete example. See the SO guidelines for further info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mess up the two possible ways of doing work with QThread:

- One is to have an object (Worker) moved to a `start()`ed QThread. This way you do work by calling slots on the Worker, the work is done when the slots execute. **You don't pause/resume this** - when the slot is done, QThread will wait for new work, the same way QApplication waits for events when it's idle.
- Second way is subclassing QThread, reimplementing run() and creating (some sort of) Worker there. Using this way you must create your "work queue" with something similar to your state variables (_working, _done, wait conditions, etc), because the thread will exit if it leaves run(), **you must pause/resume yourself**.